# Golang React Authorization

Tags: reactjs, go, jwt, authorization

I am working with **React** as Frontend and **Go** as Backend.

I use JWT token to authorize the user. So here is a JWT Middleware for secure routes.
*The problem* is I am using cookies for authorization and middleware also checks cookies to validate. While I use localStorage in React to save the JWT. *To be more exact the code is here:*

```
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{ // on Login
    Name:     "token",
    Value:    tokenString,
    Expires:  time.Now().UTC().Add(time.Hour),
    HttpOnly: true, // Prevents client-side JS from accessing the cookie
    Secure:   true, // Ensures cookie is sent over HTTPS
    Path:     "/",  // Cookie available to entire domain
})

http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{ // on Logout
    Name:     "token",
    Value:    "",
    Expires:  time.Unix(0, 0),
    HttpOnly: true,
    Secure:   true,
    Path:     "/",
})
```

here is middleware:

```
func JWTMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c, err := r.Cookie("token")
    if err != nil {
        if err == http.ErrNoCookie {
            functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, APIServerError{Error: "Unauthorized"})
            return
        }
        functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, APIServerError{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }


    tknStr := c.Value
    claims := &Claims{}

    tkn, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tknStr, claims, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            return nil, http.ErrNotSupported
        }

        return []byte("SECRET"), nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        if err == jwt.ErrSignatureInvalid {
            functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, APIServerError{Error: "Unauthorized"})
            return
        }
        functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, APIServerError{Error: err.Error()})
        return
    }
    if !tkn.Valid {
        functionalities.WriteJSON(w, http.StatusUnauthorized, APIServerError{Error: "Unauthorized"})
        return
    }

    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

}

As I writed before I use localStorage in Frontend side.

So I do not know how to send the requests like this:

```
useEffect (() => {
const userId = 'your_user_id_here'; // Replace this with actual logic to retrieve the user's ID
const fetchProfile = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/accounts/${userId}`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('authToken')}` // Assuming the token is stored in local storage
      }
    });

    // Assuming the response data structure matches the expected profile data
    setProfileData(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Profile fetch error:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
  }
};

fetchProfile();
```

}, []);

Guys, I would be more than happy if you help me or guide me to solve this problem. I am ready to rewrite the backend side and do more radical things :D

Answer (score 2):

The problem was with endpoint. So I changed this:

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/accounts/${userId}`, {}...
```

to:

```
const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/api/accounts/${userId}`, {}...
```

Here it is.

Answer (score -1):

The Authorization header now reads the token directly from the `cookie` instead of from local storage.

The `document.cookie` property is used to access cookies. The regular expression is used to extract the value of the token cookie.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchProfile = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/accounts/${userId}`, {
        // No need to read from local storage, read from cookie instead
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${document.cookie.replace(/(?:(?:^|.*;\s*)token\s*\=\s*([^;]*).*$)|^.*$/, "$1")}`
        }
      });

      // Assuming the response data structure matches the expected profile data
      setProfileData(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Profile fetch error:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
    }
  };

  fetchProfile();
}, []);
```

**Assuming the cookies are there.**

Use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie) package to play with the cookies on frontend and it provides all the functions and it is easy to use.